# Google chrome push notification cache

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, push

I'm using google chrome push notification to sent push notification on my users.
I made it like this tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/

It's working but there is a problem when i change "message" on the "sw.js" file. It's not changing imadiatly and when i sent push message users get previous message.

Help me please.

sw.js:

```
/*
*
*  Push Notifications codelab
*  Copyright 2015 Google Inc. All rights reserved.
*
*  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
*  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
*  You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
*      https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
*  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
*  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
*  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
*  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
*  limitations under the License
*
*/

// Version 0.1

'use strict';



console.log('Started', self);



self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  self.skipWaiting();
  console.log('Installed', event);
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  console.log('Activated', event);
});

self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  console.log('Push ', event);



  var title = 'Head';

  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification(title, {
      'body': 'Body!',
      'icon': 'push/images/hergunyeni-push.png'
    }));
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  console.log('Notification click: tag', event.notification.tag);
  // Android doesn't close the notification when you click it
  // See http://crbug.com/463146
  event.notification.close();

  var url = 'https://www.hergunyeni.com/tum-urunler.html?sort=p.date_added&order=DESC&utm_source=Push&utm_medium=push&utm_campaign=Yeniler&utm_content=Yeniler';
  // Check if there's already a tab open with this URL.
  // If yes: focus on the tab.
  // If no: open a tab with the URL.
  event.waitUntil(
    clients.matchAll({
      type: 'window'
    })
    .then(function(windowClients) {
      console.log('WindowClients', windowClients);
      for (var i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
        var client = windowClients[i];
        console.log('WindowClient', client);
        if (client.url === url && 'focus' in client) {
          return client.focus();
        }
      }
      if (clients.openWindow) {
        return clients.openWindow(url);
      }
    })
  );
});
```

push send php file:

```
//if ($_GET["pass"] == 'SxJYd4tZTp8pAttxiSeywnes26Jb4gGxjPU1q1q3HBm7bJ4ovE') {
   // Replace with the real server API key from Google APIs
    $apiKey = "mykey";

    // ofis büyük bilgisayar
    $registrationIDs = array( 'eQrvphoh3Kk:APA91bFQyqOX_xd3YF5pF4aXORJaUbdG61GMcwD7w-7ZYQpagiLoF9xzotjfBZv0yWC9oQTgrFpZuQWBURH_kRXGxOL-tjnLHohrtu38u4CVOIeDpdSkHo1NzZEfSHsHh8pVhfmDK_0n','ctsHPe87NgY:APA91bFIFwtfQfCmG0Np0BrHh2eXioE1vlElBd3SoQZs6vCBLf4aikvj5VtHf8J-ueh0QqQSBBQ5z-O5n2Kraqz3Gcuqc9FUASzh7gUHXEasC1gi_l7fn8e4pUa41lNoG-eK8BPPOSiz');

    // Message to be sent
    $message = "hi Shailesh";

    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
        'data' => array( "message" => $message ),
    );
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the URL, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
    //print_r($result);
    //var_dump($result);
//}
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like you are trying to send data like so:

```
 $fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
    'data' => array( "message" => $message ),
);
```

This is the *wrong* thing to do with web push. The data attribute is specific to GCM and not supported by Chrome. To send data you need to encrypt the payload. Maybe check out: https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php

Secondly, you need to change your showNotification() code in the service worker to use this data. (Try calling `console.log(event.data)`)